# No PWM Sensors found

Tags: software-installation, hardware

I am not able to get fan control working. It always says, that there are no PWM Fans even if there are. Anyone expiring something similar or got an idea how to fix it?

Kind regards

Ivan

Comment: Have you manually modified the file /etc/default/grub with a noacpi variable?

Comment: Nope, pure installation without any modifications

Answer (score 1):

I think your system can't load fancontrol driver.  You can try editing your grub file :

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub
```

and modifying the line ending with "quiet splash" to look like :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT "quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

Save the file and:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After reboot you must install appropriated software like:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors xsensors fancontrol
```

More information at

[Fix lm modules](https://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/linux/fixes/w83627hf/)